# Site not displaying properly on iPad using 978 grid

Tags: css, ipad

I've used a modified version of the 978 CSS grid on a website and it's not displaying properly on iPad or iPhone. The page container has a width of 978px width left/right padding of 12px - this is to keep the inner elements with a small margin down each side, but keep within the 1024px device width. In theory, this *should* be displaying correctly... but it's not. It's like the page is slightly too wide and I can't figure out what's causing it.

The site is here - if someone is able to have a look and advise of a solution, that'd be awesome!

http://www.trendhfl.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean iPad landscape mode, no? Try using instead of the current viewport meta, this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`